# How to preserve the dataset encoding sent from the backend for the google chart rendering?

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, google-visualization

A google line chart renders correctly when I give data like this:
`

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
function drawBasic() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'keyword');
data.addRows([['56', 2], ['77', 3], ['54', 6]])
```

When I send the data from the backend to be embedded in the data.addRows, it modifies my string values:

backend return code:

`da=[['56', 2], ['77', 3], ['54', 6]]
return render_template("line_chart.html", data=da)`

line_chart.html code:

```
function drawBasic() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'keyword');
dataset = {{(data)}}
data.addRows(dataset)
```

When I check the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

and the dataset is modified
`dataset =[[&#39;56&#39;, 2], [&#39;77&#39;, 3], [&#39;54&#39;, 6]]`

How to prevent this modification?

Comment: Use the `unescape()` function that decodes an encoded string.

Comment: @NejiSoltani Thanks! However, how to change the entire dataset?
Isn't there a way by which the dataset maintains its form when it is coming from the backend?

Comment: What backend are you using. It seems it is urlencoding your return.

Comment: what does this line `dataset = {{(data)}}` do ?
I dont see that it does the same as `data.addRows([['56', 2], ['77', 3], ['54', 6]])` maybe it's `data.addRows(dataset)`

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier I am using Flask.

Comment: @NejiSoltani Sorry, I edited the question. It is indeed, `data.addRows(dataset)`

Comment: can you try with {{ data|safe }}